# Actual changing of XML file in Javascript / AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, html, save

since days I have been searching for answers but couldn't get what I am searching for.

I program a realtime webapp using *Javascript* and *HTML5*. For saving game stats I wanted to use a *XML-file*, that holds all the levelpoints and the achievements *and lies locally within the same folder as the html*.

So I found out, how to **read** out the values stored in the XML-file with an *XMLHttpRequest*. The problem is, that I can only **change** the node values client-sided, so if I empty the cache or simply reload the page, the XML does hold the original values.

To **save** the XML server-side is what I want. I hope, you can help me :)

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` (an AJAX request) to send the updated XML to the server and then have a server side script (using a server side language such as PHP for example) which will replace the contents of the XML file on the server.

Here's for example how you could send the XML to the server:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/some_script', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};

var xml = '<foo>Bar</foo>';
xhr.send(xml);
```

Comment: So if I now send the `xml` with `xhr.send(xml)` where do I have to put the php, that saves the xml? Sorry if this question looks stupid, but this topic is #neuland for me ^^

Comment: You have to put the PHP file on the web server that is hosting your application. I just gave PHP as an example. Depending on your scenario you could use any other server side language.

Comment: Oh, I don't actually host my application on a web server. It runs locally on mobile devices (or for debugging on a pc):)

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot modify files using javascript.

Comment: Me too, but there are so many apps that use html5 and javascript and though save game stats. So, I will search for other solutions. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The apps that save game stats, store the data locally on the client. They don't post on to the server. If they are, then they would need internet connectivity and post data to the game server. where again there would be a PHP page or a servlet to handle data.

For client side storage, HTML5 has options. Please check the below link 
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html